# Azure Function in Javascript never returns

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions

I am able to get the eventhandlers to run but the function never returns the correct resultText. Where do I need to put the return to give me this value? I have confirmed that the stream translates correctly and the function returns a 204 but with no resultText.

I have tried to put the return outside of the sessionStopped event but this returns an empty string.  The result should be the translated result text. It does return technically but the resultText is empty.

```
app.http('jsTranslateVMSpanishToEnglish', {
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: async (request, context) => {
        
        // create the push stream we need for the speech sdk.
        var format = sdk.AudioStreamFormat.getWaveFormatPCM(48000, 16, 1); 
var pushStream = sdk.AudioInputStream.createPushStream(format);
        //var pushStream = sdk.AudioInputStream.createPushStream();
       var resultText = '';


        var blobName = JSON.parse(await request.text()).body.BlobName;//'msg_3640d487-44bf-4f61-b225-b2e71fafa096.wav';//request.body.BlobName;
        context.log("BlobName: " + blobName);
        //context.log("Request:" + await request.text());
        //context.log("Blob:" + await request.body.BlobName);
        var stream =  blobService.createReadStream(containerName, blobName).on('error', function (error) {
            context.log(error);
        }).on('data', function(arrayBuffer) {
            
           //context.log('Pushing chunk of size: ' + arrayBuffer.byteLength);
            pushStream.write(arrayBuffer.slice());
          }).on('end', function() {
            
            //context.log('End of file reached.');
            pushStream.close();
          });


          context.log("Now recognizing from: " + blobName);
          
       
          // now create the audio-config pointing to our stream and
          // the speech config specifying the language.
          var audioConfig = sdk.AudioConfig.fromStreamInput(pushStream);
          var speechConfig = sdk.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(subscriptionKey, serviceRegion);
          
          // setting the recognition language to English.
          speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage = "en-US";
          
          // create the speech recognizer.
          var recognizer = new sdk.SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);
          
          if(recognizer == undefined) {
            context.log("ERROR: recognizer is undefined");
          }
          else
          {
            context.log("recognizer is defined");
          // start the recognizer and wait for a result.
      recognizer.startContinuousRecognitionAsync();
           
      recognizer.recognized = (reco, e) => {
        try {
            const res = e.result;

            resultText += res.text;
            
        } catch (error) {
            context.log(error);
        }
      };

      recognizer.sessionStopped = (reco, e) => {
        
         reco.stopContinuousRecognitionAsync();
         reco.close();
        //recognizer.stopContinuousRecognitionAsync();
        //recognizer.close();
      **  return { body: resultText };**
    };

        }

      
      
    }
});
```

Comment: 204 means no content

Comment: That is correct!

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own issue with this adjustment:

```
app.http("jsTranslateVMSpanishToEnglish", {
  methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  authLevel: "anonymous",
  handler: async (request, context) => {
    // create the push stream we need for the speech sdk.
    var format = sdk.AudioStreamFormat.getWaveFormatPCM(48000, 16, 1);
    var pushStream = sdk.AudioInputStream.createPushStream(format);
    
    

    var blobName =   JSON.parse(await request.text()).body.BlobName; //request.body.BlobName;
    context.log("BlobName: " + blobName);
    
    var stream = blobService
      .createReadStream(containerName, blobName)
      .on("error", function (error) {
        context.log(error);
      })
      .on("data", function (arrayBuffer) {
        //context.log('Pushing chunk of size: ' + arrayBuffer.byteLength);
        pushStream.write(arrayBuffer.slice());
      })
      .on("end", function () {
        //context.log('End of file reached.');
        pushStream.close();
      });

    context.log("Now recognizing from: " + blobName);

    // now create the audio-config pointing to our stream and
    // the speech config specifying the language.
    var audioConfig = sdk.AudioConfig.fromStreamInput(pushStream);
    var speechConfig = sdk.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(
      subscriptionKey,
      serviceRegion
    );

    // setting the recognition language to English.
    speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage = "en-US";

    // create the speech recognizer.
    var recognizer = new sdk.SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);

    if (recognizer == undefined) {
      context.log("ERROR: recognizer is undefined");
    } else {
      context.log("recognizer is defined");

      const resultText = await getResultText(recognizer);

      context.log("Result Text: " + resultText);
      return { body: resultText };
    }
  },
});

async function getResultText(recognizer) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var resultText = "";
    recognizer.recognized = (reco, e) => {
      try {
        const res = e.result;

        resultText += res.text;
      } catch (error) {
        reject(error);
      }
    };

    recognizer.sessionStopped = (reco, e) => {
      recognizer.stopContinuousRecognitionAsync();
      recognizer.close();
      resolve(resultText);
    };

    recognizer.startContinuousRecognitionAsync();
  });
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).